# Computer shuts down when closing the lid and no power

Tags: 18.04, suspend, dell, shutdown, lid

Using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on a Dell xps 15.
Every time I close the lid and the computer is disconnected from power it shuts down. When I open the lid again it restarts.
I managed to disabled suspending when closing the lid (through gnome-tweaks) which solves the problem but it wastes a lot of battery.
Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to prevent this from happening? >> Prevent what? Please clarify question an the title too

Comment: When you say is "restarts" do you mean that it reboots?  Will you please execute `cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf` and paste the results of that command into your question?

Comment: Also please add the outputs of `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action` and `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action`